# ¿Existe algún uso para basic_string<T> cuando T no es un tipo de caracter?

Tags: c++, string

Se trata de la versión en Español de mi [misma pregunta en el StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775405/is-there-any-use-for-basic-stringt-where-t-is-not-a-character-type), he decidido copiarla a este StackOverflow para tener puntos de vista adicionales (ya que no he dado con una respuesta satisfactoria en la versión en Inglés).

---

La declaración de la plantilla `std::string` de C++ [es la siguiente](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

El tipo `CharT` puede ser `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` y `char32_t`; pero al fin y al cabo `basic_string` es una plantilla y puede ser instanciada con otros `CharT` y otros allocators. Pero mientras que puedo pensar en algunos casos de uso para otros allocators no se me ocurre ningún caso de uso para cadenas de otros tipos de datos, por ejemplo:

```
using istring = std::basic_string<int>;
```

Una cadena de enteros, no podemos inicializarlo como cadena (obviamente) ni como una cadena `char32_t` (esto no es tan obvio, al menos para mi); pero podemos inicializarlo con `initializer_list` siempre y cuando el tipo contenido en la lista sea convertible a `int`:

```
istring error1("test");   // Error!
istring error2(U"test");  // Error!
istring error3{"test"};   // Error!
istring error4{U"test"};  // Error!
istring error5 = "test";  // Error!
istring error6 = U"test"; // Error!

istring correcto1({U't', U'e', U's', U't'});
istring correcto2 = {U't', U'e', U's', U't'};
istring correcto3({'t', 'e', 's', 't'});
istring correcto4 = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
```

Pero incluso si conseguimos inicializar una cadena de enteros, no podemos usarlo de la manera habitual:

```
std::cout << correcto1; // Error! esperaba 116101115116
```

Los únicos `basic_string` preparados para ser usados con `std::cout` son los *normales*, esto tiene sentido: al fin y al cabo no podemos asumir como se supone qe debemos mostrar una cadena de enteros o una cadena de `MiClaseChachi`.

Pero de todas maneras, crear instancias *raras* de `basic_string` está permitido; por un lado no está prohibido por la falta de características que limiten este uso (como los concepts) y por otro lado programar `basic_string` sin limitar el tipo subyacente es más fácil que hacerlo con estas limitaciones (sin disponer de concepts) por lo que me pregunto:

- ¿Existe algún uso para  `std::basic_string<T>` cuando `T` no es un tipo de caracter?

En cuanto a *algún uso* pienso en cosas que sólo puedan ser conseguidas con cadenas de `T` y no puedan ser conseguidas por vectores de `T` (o que sea significantemente más difícil de hacer), en otras palabras:

- ¿Os habéis encontrado en la situación en que una cadena de `T` sea la mejor opción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta donde yo llego, `basic_string` está pensada únicamente para gestión de cadenas como tal.

¿Por qué es una plantilla?

Porque en su momento se vió que se podía reutilizar el código para los diferentes tipos de cadenas que te puedes encontrar en C++, que son los que has enumerado.

¿Por qué deja la plantilla libertad para, por ejemplo, definir una cadena de tipo int?

Básicamente porque las plantillas en C++ no han dispuesto de mecanismos de control que limitasen la disponibilidad a la hora de especializarse. Desde C++11 tienes `type_traits` que unido a SFINAE te permite implementar bloqueos para evitar usos bizarros en los templates. El coste asociado a limitar sus usos es que el template se vuelve más complicado de mantener.

¿Podría tener otros usos `basic_string`?

Desde mi punto de vista no.

`basic_string` es una clase pensada para asumir las particularidades propias de las cadenas de texto en C++ que no dejan de ser vectores de tipo `char`, `wchar_t`, ...

Por otro lado, la librería estándar de C++ ha tenido de siempre un soporte sumamente pobre al multi-idioma. `char` únicamente te sirve para caracteres ASCII y trabajar con `wchar_t` puede ser tortuoso y complicado además de que no es todo lo portable que a uno le gustaría. Al final la mejor alternativa en este caso es tirar de librerías con mejor soporte para este tipo de situaciones (como puede ser el caso de Qt con `QString`).

Una cosa es que la librería no le ponga coto al template y otra cosa muy distinta es dar usos bizarros a un template. Dicho de otra manera: puedes usar un soplete industrial para calentar la comida pero a mi al menos nadie tiene que decirme que eso es peligroso y que hay mejores maneras de conseguir mi objetivo.

Para almacenar cadenas de ints, por ejemplo, tienes a tu disposición un surtido abanico de contenedores que cumplen su misión en prácticamente todas las situaciones. No veo qué puede aportar abusar del template `basic_string`.

En cualquier caso estaré pendiente a las respuestas tanto de aquí como del bando inglés por si alguien me enseña usos que merezcan la pena :)

Un saludo.

Comment: Veo que tenemos un punto de vista parecido. Me parece intuir que ambos pensamos que la plantilla `basic_string` carece de limitaciones a su tipo subyacente *simplemente* por no complicar la implementación. Se me acaba de ocurrir que puede haber algo exclusivo de las cadenas de `int` que no se puede conseguir con vectores de `int`: ¿un `basic_string<int>` entraría en la optimización de cadenas pequeñas? (Small String Optimization).